# Unsigned 64bit subtract-with-borrow in Standard C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, integer, c++20

I'm writing a (compile-time-)fixed-width unsigned big integer. To implement subtraction, a subtract-with-borrow primitive is required. When efficient platform-specific implementation isn't available (e.g. x86_64's `_subborrow_u64` intrinsic), it needs to be implemented in Standard C++.

I've been able to come up with the following implementation:

```
#include <stdint.h>

inline
auto subtract_with_borrow(
    uint64_t& result,
    uint64_t left, uint64_t right,
    uint64_t borrow /* only 0 or 1 */)
-> uint64_t /* borrow */
{
    result = left - right - borrow;
    return (left < right) | ((left == right) & borrow);
}
```

However, I suspect it might be suboptimal since it requires roughly twice as many operations as add-with-carry (don't review it):

```
inline
auto add_with_carry(
    uint64_t& result,
    uint64_t left, uint64_t right,
    uint64_t carry /* only 0 or 1 */)
-> uint64_t /* carry */
{
    result = left + right;
    uint64_t next_carry = result < left;
    result += carry;
    return next_carry;
}
```

I intuitively expect a certain symmetry to exist here. Can `subtract_with_borrow` be simplified further? Or is my intuition wrong and this is indeed the optimal implementation?

And no, the compiler optimization doesn't manage to magically transform it into a better version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, but the issue is that your add_with_carry lacks the carry propagation in subtract_with_borrow.

That's a general observation - if the new code looks more complicated than the old code, you should also consider that the old code lacked something.

Consider the call add_with_carray(0,2^64-1,1):

```
  result=0+(2^64-1); // 2^64-1
  next_carry=(2^64-1)<0; // False
  result+=1; // causing result=0; due to overflow
  return next_carry; // 0
```

In general you should test such routines for carry=0,1 and left, right close to 0 and 2^64-1

Answer (score 2):

Prefer to use the C++ `<cstdint>` header that puts identifiers in the correct namespace, rather than the deprecated C-compatibility header.  This is particularly important in header files, as these affect every translation unit that uses them.

> ```
>     uint64_t carry /* only 0 or 1 */)
> ```

I dislike that comment style.  Because the comment is almost, but not quite, at the end of line, it's very easy to miss the `)` hiding there, and mis-parse.

If `carry` can only be 0 or 1, does it really make sense to pass as a 64-bit type?  Certainly the bitwise arithmetic to create the carry-out is unlikely to create better code than plain logic `&&` and `||` (any decent compiler can avoid unnecessary jumps because none of the operands have side-effects).

The test cases seem to have missed an important case in `add_with_carry()` (I know you said not to review that, but it's relevant for the subtract function):

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(add_with_carry, ci_causes_co)
{
    uint64_t small = 0;
    uint64_t big = ~small;
    uint64_t result;
    EXPECT_EQ(add_with_carry(result, small, big, 0), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(result, big);
    EXPECT_EQ(add_with_carry(result, small, big, 1), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(result, 0);
}
```

The corresponding test of subtraction succeeds:

```
TEST(subtract_with_borrow, ci_causes_co)
{
    uint64_t small = 0;
    uint64_t big = ~small;
    uint64_t result;
    EXPECT_EQ(subtract_with_borrow(result, 0, 0, 0), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(result, 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(subtract_with_borrow(result, 0, 0, 1), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(result, big);
}
```

So the two functions are not directly comparable.  It's a shame you didn't include the tests for review - given that you've missed probably the most important boundary case, then the testing may well be deficient in other ways too.

To make the tests pass, I needed to make the logic of the two functions equivalent to each other:

```
static
auto subtract_with_borrow(uint64_t& result,
                          uint64_t left, uint64_t right,
                          bool borrow)
{
    result = left - right - borrow;
    return left < right || left == right && borrow;
}

static
auto add_with_carry(uint64_t& result,
                    uint64_t left, uint64_t right,
                    bool carry)
{
    result = left + right + carry;
    return left > ~right || left == ~right && carry;
}
```

Now that both tests pass, the corresponding assembly outputs look very similar to each other.

Comment: I disagree about `<cstdint>`. I believe that `[u]intN_t` should've been fundamental types like `int`, and the fact that they are implemented as typedefs is a historical mistake. When considered like that, putting them into `std` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You are correct about my `add_with_carry` being broken, of course. But I believe an implementation exactly symmetric with `subtract_with_borrow` would be `result = left + right + carry; return result < left || result == left && carry;`

Comment: You could do it that way, and change `subtract_with_borrow` to match.  It's arguably better to not use `result` in computing the return value, though, as that allows more parallelism in a superscalar CPU.

Comment: I'm not convinced that _optional_ types could, never mind should, have been fundamental!